# C++ Need Help Overloading += for a MyString Class

Tags: c++

I'm working on writing my own string class and am having trouble with overloading the += operator for a MyString being +='d to a char. I figured this would work but with no luck. Here's the implementation I tried. Any assistance on getting it to work correctly will be much appreciated.

```
MyString& MyString::operator +=(char c)
{
    char derp[1] = {c};
    strcat(value, derp);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? If not, why do you even code your own `string` class?

Comment: char * derp = "x"; derp[0] = c;

Comment: @Griwes, they could just be trying to learn.

Comment: Yes it is homework, it seems like a very easy overload to write. I'm assuming my problem is it's very late and I've been staring at the computer screen doing other things for the last few hours. Long story short, my brain is running at a very slow rate, so I kinda spaced a lot of details.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko, this question shows that OP doesn't even know that `string` must handle resizing of the buffer to work. I'm sure there are papers out there that describes the standard implementation of proper string class - they are better places to learn such thing than blindly trying to implement it.

Comment: @Griwes, like I said it is late and I rushed into it, I apologize for blindly trying to implement it and then turning for help too early.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not going to work for several reasons:

1. `derp` is not a null-terminated array, which it has to be if you pass it as a parameter to `strcat`
2. There is no check that the buffer that `value` represents can actually hold more data; neither is there a facility to make sure that the buffer is always null-terminated (which again it needs to be because you are passing it to `strcat`)
3. Even if you correct the above, your string class will never be able to include the character `\0` as part of a string value because that will be mistaken for a null terminator; in technical terms, your string class would not be "binary safe"; to fix this you need to drop `strcat` and similar functions entirely and switch to `memcpy` and friends

Apart from the above, overloading `operator +=` like this allows for code such as

```
MyString str("foo");
foo += 80; // this compiles, but should it?
```

Finally, the `str***` family of functions is going to get needlessly slower as your strings are getting larger (because they have to scan the string from the beginning each time in order to determine where it ends). Keeping your own length variable and switching to `mem***` is going to fix this issue as well.

Comment: Thank you for the very informational response. I like that you also gave reasoning to why it was correct and the problems that doing it the other way would cause. Thanks again lol :P

Answer (score 1):

The use of `strcat` is incorrect as it requires a null terminated source string and is being provided with a buffer with no null terminator.

`value` will only be capable of holding a finite number of characters, and there is no attempt to increase the size of `value`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `value` is large enough and you retain the length of the string inside your instance, I'd say:

```
value[size] = c;
value[size+1] = '\0';
```